# Get calendars list using exchange service with office 365 login directly

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

I've a web application where i have used office 365 login (for sharepoint) to authenticate the user and then redirect to my web application.

Now i want to access the logged in office 365 user's calendar and add events, get list of calendars etc.. I've looked into office 365 API but it uses OAuth2 authentication which i don't want to go for.

So i went for ExchangeService API but it needs the NetworkCredentials of the user, which means i have to add the username and password for each user, which is not possible.

Is there any way i can use the logged in office 365 user's details and access the calendars and events?

Comment: How do you authenticate users in web application? What do you mean by office 365 login?

Comment: @FIL: My application uses sharepoint to store documents, so i use office 365 login to authenticate and get the refresh token and redirect to my application .

Comment: So you are using OAuth2 authentication...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to access Office365 resources like mailboxes, calendars, contacts etc. is by using [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph).

There are many [SDK and code samples](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/code-samples-and-sdks) to start developing with Graph API. [Here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/aspnetmvc) is a guide for ASP.NET MVC app.

Comment: I tried using Microsoft Graph API but in my application i'm using OAuth2 login, but after login i'm redirecting them to sharepoint, from where the user can go to my application. So, when i try to authenticate the user using Microsoft Graph API, the context is different. I'm getting different context when trying to access using 
         
         
         
    "ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value"